# Panel collapse(expand) from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with a left hand menu that collapses/displays content when the user clicks on a link. This works perfectly using an href, data-target, data-collapse-group, and data-toggle as found in my example: http://jsfiddle.net/ns_19/rff70hfL/

Working Code Link example:

```
    <li style="font-size: small">
        <a href="#collapse2" data-target="#collapse2" 
        data-collapse- group="myDivs" data-toggle="collapse">
        Anti-Corruption Laws</a>
    </li>
```

JavaScript to expand/collapse panel

```
$("[data-collapse-group='myDivs']").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("[data-collapse-group='myDivs']:not([data-target='" + $this.data   ("target") + "'])").each(function () {
        $($(this).data("target")).removeClass("in").addClass('collapse');
    });
});
```

I now need to add a content map that would link directly to each panel on a page.  As shown here (Content Map - http://jsfiddle.net/ns_19/fsL7pntf/). I can access the page only with the default panel expanded but I cannot directly access any of the other panels currently collapsed.

I have tried extending the href to include the form name and searched for any existing submitted questions on multiple sites. Regardless of the link I select, only the first or default section of the page is displayed.

I believe the issue is the JavaScript on the called page is not receiving the value to act upon it. Does anyone have an idea how I get the #Collapse to be caught, and processed, by JavaScript on the page I'm trying to access?

Note, these pages originally are set up with a master and content but were placed together due to jsfiddle restraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out through trial and error.  However if someone wants to offer suggestions to improve I would appreciate it.

There are several modifications to be made in both files:

1. Change the href on the ContentMap to: (note sending the # never was sent if I use #collapse2). Do this for all links.

   ```
   <a title="Insider Trading" href="../Forms/Assets.aspx?section=collapse2">Insider Trading</a>
   ```
2. In the code-behind of my master page I added the following two code blocks.  This simply checks the query string if a specific section has been passed and if it has, sets the value of a hidden field on the master page.

   ```
   protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
   {
       NavToSection();
   }

   protected void NavToSection() {
       List<string> keys = new List<string>(Request.QueryString.AllKeys);

       if(keys.Contains("section")) {
           this.HiddenMaster.Value = Request.QueryString["section"];
       }
   }
   ```
3. On the master page I added the hidden field and the following two JavaScript functions. The `$(document).ready(checkCollapse);` function simply calls the `checkCollapse(jQuery)` when the document "is ready"

   ```
   <input type="hidden" id="HiddenMaster" name="HiddenMaster" value="default" runat="server" />    

   function checkCollapse(jQuery) {
       var oValToCheck = document.getElementById('HiddenMaster').value; //get the value of the hidden field in the master "HiddenMaster"

       if (oValToCheck != 'default') {  //If the HiddenMaster's value is not equal to 'default' then continue.
           var oCollapse = document.getElementById(oValToCheck);  // Search the DOM for the object I am looking for to expand.
           var isTargetExpanded = $(oCollapse).hasClass('in');  // Check if section already is already expanded.  Not really needed here anymore
           $(oCollapse).removeClass('collapse').addClass("in"); // expand selected target by changing the css classes assigned to it
           var $this = $(this);  // get reference to this page.  JQuery reference 
           $this.data("target", "#" + oValToCheck); // assign the target 

           //cycle through all "myDivs" and remove 'in' or add 'collapse' to any div where target is not equal to passed value
           $("[data-collapse-group='myDivs']:not([data-target='" + $this.data("target") + "'])").each(function () { 
               $($(this).data("target")).removeClass("in").addClass('collapse');
           });
       }
   }

   $(document).ready(checkCollapse); // Execute the checkCollapse function once the document 'isready'
   ```